# Selenium webdriver getting element after page changes

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

Very simple question, basically I'm trying to get the text of a li element after clicking on another link.  The link will cause the li orders to change.  Whenever I try to get the text, it will return the text before the order changes.  How do I get the li text after the order has changed from clicking a link?  the link doesn't reload the page itself.

Here's what I'm using to get the element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[id^='coupon_']:nth-of-type(1) p.brand")).getText();
```

The change itself will be from:

```
<div id="id1">
  <ul class="pods">
    <li rel="" title="some text" id="coupon_1" data-pos="1">
      ...
      <p class="brand">brand1</p>
      ...
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="id1">
  <ul class="pods">
    <li rel="" title="some text" id="coupon_5" data-pos="1">
      ...
      <p class="brand">brand5</p>
      ...
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I had similar situations where I would use wait.until for the element that changes to appear and then get it but in this case the li element is already present, but just changes after clicking on the link.  How can I get the new element text?  thanks!

Comment: Do you know what exactly changes if you click the link? Could you expose that in terms of HTML: provide the HTML before and after.

Comment: It would change from:
`<div><ul class="blah"><li id="coupon_1"><p class="brand">brand1</p>...</li></ul></div>`
to:
`<div><ul class="blah"><li id="coupon_5"><p class="brand">brand5</p>...</li></ul></div>`

i would not know the id ahead of time though when I click on the link

Comment: Please edit the question and add this information into it.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong: basically, the amount of coupons changes if you click the link?..

Comment: not the amount, just the content changes, such as the id, brand name etc. everything else is the same

Comment: Okay, can we rely on the `data-pos` attribute change?

Answer (score 4):

You can wait for the id change in the `li`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
// wait for the new li to appear
WebElement li = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("coupon_5")));
System.out.println(li.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.brand")).getText().trim());
```

or if there are multiple possibilities for the new id then you can wait for the old id element to become stale.

```
// get the original li that will be changed
WebElement oldLi = driver.findElement(By.id("coupon_1"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
// wait for the original li to go stale... change
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(oldLi));
// grab the new element by whatever the new id is
WebElement newLi = driver.findElement(By.id("coupon_5"));
System.out.println(newLi.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.brand")).getText().trim());
```

Comment: Yeah, a perfect use case for  `stalenessOf`! +1.

Comment: using stalenessOf is great for detecting page transitions. Read [this article](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html)...it's where I learned about these concepts. Good stuff.